# K-means clustering - Fix one centroid & find other

Tags: python, k-means

I'm trying to identify ideal location to open a warehouse through COG approach using k-means clustering. But, the problem I am facing is on how to account for the factory location. Below is my output plotted in Folium map

[image]

I would ideally like to deliver places near factory from the factory itself & use warehouse for locations far off from factory. I was thinking I can do this by fixing one centroid in k-means and find another k to identify the warehouse.

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear what you want to achieve. I think you want to identify the best location to set up a warehouse. If its the case, you can use mixed integer programming to solve this.
[See this](https://www.r-orms.org/mixed-integer-linear-programming/practicals/warehouse-location-problem/)

Comment: Useful article. This is what I want to achieve. But, couple of questions. Is there a similar article in Python? Also, how do I include my factory location in this analysis?

Comment: You can use python libraries such as pymoo and pyOpt in the same way. You can use the names for your factory locations. But you should define distance as your data. Please note this is different from a typical data science problem. this is an optimization problem

Comment: Agreed it is an optimization problem. But, wouldn't the clustering would do the same. It would identify the best possible centroid Isn't it?

Comment: Yes if you have set of points and you just want to identify the centre, then clustering would be enough. But if you want to identify the centre subject to some constraints like reduce the cost or something, then MIP is the best approach. Best location might not be the center when there are some constraints

Comment: But, the link you share and the MIP you are talking solves only if you have a set of locations for your warehouses. While I am trying to identify the location at the first place.